# Y86 processor reference code

Tags: cpu, verilog

I am trying to make simple version of the Y86 CPU. I would like a reference Y86 verilog code.

Is this available?

Comment: Voting to close as resource rec.

Answer (score 0):

The Y86 Instruction Set Architecture is a pseudo-language based on x86 for teaching purposes.

I am not sure that the verilog code for it exists under an open-source licence and as part of a course I would have thought it was coursework to write it yourself.